# How to rank numbers in array by Unix?

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I am thinking if there exists any name for such a simple function which returns the order of numbers in an array. 
I would really love to do this ranking by minimalist way and with basic Unix commands but I cannot get anything to my mind than basic find-and-loop which is not so elegant. 
Assume you have an array of numbers

```
17 
94 
3 
52 
4 
4 
9
```

Expected output where duplicates just receive the same ID; how to handle duplicates is not critical so feel to take shortcuts:

```
4 
6 
1 
5 
2 
2 
3
```

Motivation: I saw today many users using many different ways to solve this problem and doing much manual steps with Spreadsheet; so I started to think the minimalist way to do it.

### Comparing the ranking algorithm to Google's Average ranking

In Google Spreadsheet, do `=arrayformula(rank.AVG(A:A,A:A,true))` and you get as a benchmark as ascending order like the first expected output

```
17  5
94  7
3   1
52  6
4   2.5
4   2.5
9   4
```

where you see that my initial ranking algorithm is biased. 
I think to be able to set the dataset location would be helpful here.

Comment: Apart from being in reverse order, the minor "biased" difference comes from counting duplicated items as 2 places instead of one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If that list was in a `file`, one per line, I'd do something like:

```
sort -nu file |
  awk 'NR == FNR {rank[$0] = NR; next}
      {print rank[$0]}' - file
```

If it was in a `zsh` `$array`:

```
sorted=(${(nou)array})
for i ($array) echo $sorted[(i)$i]
```

That's the same principle as for the `awk` version above, the *rank* is the index `NR`/`(i)` in the numerically (`-n`/`(n)`) ordered (`sort`/`(o)`), uniqued (`-u`/`(u)`) list of elements.

For your average rank:

```
sort -n file |
  awk 'NR == FNR {rank[$0] += NR; n[$0]++; next}
  {print rank[$0] / n[$0]}' - file
```

Which gives:

```
5
7
1
6
2.5
2.5
4
```

(use `sort -rn` to reverse the order like in your *Google Spreadsheet* version).

Comment: Please, see the benchmark of Google's average ranking in the body. Maybe, it can simplify your proposal. To be able to set the dataset location to get biased and/or unbiased would be great.

Comment: @Masi, see edit for average ranking. I don't follow your sentence about _biased/unbiased_ and _dataset location_. Possibly your question needs more context.

Answer (score 8):

```
nl x | sort  -k 2n | nl | sort -k 2n | cut -f1
```

... it has a slightly  different behavior in case of duplicates:

```
 nl x | sort  -k 2n | nl | sort -k 2n | cut -f1,3
 5  17 
 7  94 
 1  3 
 6  52 
 2  4 
 3  4 
 4  9
```

Comment: Please, see the benchmark of Google's average ranking in the body. Maybe, it can simplify your proposal. To be able to set the dataset location to get biased and/or unbiased would be great.

Comment: @masi, appart duplicates, you get  the Google's ranking if you just sort in reverse order: `nl x | sort  -k 2rn | nl | sort -k 2n | cut -f1,3`

Answer (score 6):

With just GNU awk:

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {numbers[$1]=1; next} 
    FNR == 1 {
        n = asorti(numbers, sorted, "@ind_num_asc")
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) rank[sorted[i]] = i
    }
    {print rank[$1]}
' file file
```

Comment: Note that `numbers[$1]=1` can be simplified to just `numbers[$1]` as you don't care about the values of that hash.

Comment: I find that too obscure for my tastes, and prefer an assignment to create the array element.

Comment: @masi, how is that "google average ranking" implanted? I strongly suspect it will not simplify my code at all

Comment: On the other hand, I did wonder what was the significance of assigning the value 1 to the array. For me, `h[key]` is idiomatic of assigning the key of a hash, while `a[key]=1` would be idiomatic of giving a _true_ value to the hash element of by that _key_.