# Compute rank in awk?

Tags: awk

I want to compute the rank of an array that may contain duplicate numbers in awk.

In R, it looks like this.

```
R> x=c(92, 3, 1, 4, 15, 4)
R> rank(x)
[1] 6.0 2.0 1.0 3.5 5.0 3.5
```

[How to rank numbers in array by Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310916/how-to-rank-numbers-in-array-by-unix)

Here is a solution that does not allow duplicate numbers. Does anybody have an awk function to return the rank of an array with duplicate numbers?

```
awk '
    FNR == NR {numbers[$1]=1; next} 
    FNR == 1 {
        n = asorti(numbers, sorted, "@ind_num_asc")
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) rank[sorted[i]] = i
    }
    {print rank[$1]}
' file file
```

Comment: See the .5 fraction in the result of the R code example. The awk code can not return a fraction in the rank.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use R? Why reinvent the wheel? Do you need it to run where R is not available or would an R script that can read input from a file and run from the commandline be enough?

Comment: I have other things that need to be done in awk. So having a rank function in awk is convenient in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of the `rank` function in R in the case of multiplicity *k* appears to be to average the next *k* ranks (using up an additional `k-1` ranks in the process):

```
$ awk '
    FNR == NR {numbers[$1]++; next}
    FNR == 1 {
        n = asorti(numbers, sorted, "@ind_num_asc")
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            k = numbers[sorted[i]]; 
            rank[sorted[i]] = i + offset + (k-1)/2; 
            offset += (k-1)
        }
    }
    {print rank[$1]}
' file file
6
2
1
3.5
5
3.5
```

Note that `numbers[$1]=1` has been changed to `numbers[$1]++` to record the multiplicities.

Comment: OK second try - I think the arithmetic is correct now (mean = start + 1/2*range)